# how i can use a string that have the same structure how a xml file for a treeview?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, parsing, treeview

hi how i can use a string that have the same structure how a xml file for a treeview. 
For Example here is a part of the string coontent..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LM-X STAT_VERSION="3.32">
<LICENSE_PATH TYPE="NETWORK" HOST="6200@serv005" SERVER_VERSION="4.4.4" UPTIME="53 day(s) 23 hour(s) 0 min(s) 3 sec(s)">
<FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="111720" TOTAL_LICENSES="147000" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL">
<USER NAME="SYSTEM" HOST="SERV171" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" SHARE_CUSTOM="hweuser:172.16.11.115"/>
>
....
```

this is only a string.

I want to use this string how a xml file...can i convert this string do a (virtual) xml and fill my treeview with the nodes of FEATURE or USER?

my c# code:

```
 private void btnShowLicstate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string command = "\"C:\\lmxendutil.exe\" -licstatxml -host serv005 -port 6200";

           string output = ExecuteCommand(command);
           string final_output = output.Substring(90, output.Length-90);

            // here i want to parse the string in a xml format string xD and load this in    the       treeview

           txtOutput.Text = final_output; 
        }

        static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process = Process.Start(processInfo);

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            process.Close();

            return output; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class,
you can create one from your String with XDocument.Parse(String) or XDocument.Load(Path).

Then use the following functions to populate your Tree View (found at [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/01501a8e-898a-465e-92f9-ad6a16aae065/)):

```
    private void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, XDocument doc)
    {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(doc.Root.Name.LocalName);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        BuildNodes(treeNode, doc.Root);
    }

    private void BuildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, XElement element)
    {
        foreach (XNode child in element.Nodes())
        {
            switch (child.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    XElement childElement = child as XElement;
                    TreeNode childTreeNode = new TreeNode(childElement.Name.LocalName);
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add(childTreeNode);
                    BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    XText childText = child as XText;
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(childText.Value));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of binding an xml document to a treeview:

```
// we cannot bind the TreeView directly to an XmlDocument
// so we must create an XmlDataSource and assign the XML text
XmlDataSource XDdataSource = new XmlDataSource();
XDdataSource.ID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();  // unique ID is required
XDdataSource.Data = XDoc.OuterXml;

// we want the full name displayed in the tree so 
// do custom databindings
TreeNodeBinding Binding = new TreeNodeBinding();
Binding.TextField = "FullName";
Binding.ValueField = "ID";
TreeView1.DataBindings.Add(Binding);

// Hook up the XmlDataSource to the TreeView
TreeView1.DataSource = XDdataSource;
TreeView1.DataBind();
```